# How do I get away from the guards in Skyrim with low health?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I went into Whiterun, and they started chasing me. I was doing the Companion missions trying to get to be a werewolf and I was on my last mission. I think when they chased me into the Companions safe house I was almost dead.

I think I'm at level 4 with no healing potions, and now every time my game loads I'm standing there with no health and they hit me one time and I die. Sometimes I can make a run for it but when I get to the bottom steps I drop dead.

I tried loading saved games but they do the same thing. Somehow they all Autosaved and now I'm stuck.

Can someone please tell me how to get out of this situation? The healing spells I have aren't effective enough.

Comment: Where are you autosaved? If you are by the door, try to turn around and  get out that way. The guards outside may attack, but are few and easily avoided.

Comment: It auto saves if you enter whiterun so can't you just load a previous autosave before you entered as a werewolf?

Answer (score 5):

Try to walk towards them with your weapon drawn, then when they want to attack you, hold "R" (Or the controller button) to yield. If you're lucky they will try to arrest you. Just pay the bounty or serve jailtime and you'll be good to go.

If they will still attack you, you can try typing "tgm" in the in-game console which you can open by pressing "~". This only works on PC, and will turn on godmode. You can try to get to safety after which you can continue your game while trying to stay safe until the bounty wears off.

Comment: Good suggestion on the console.  Personally as a level 4 I'd just restart, as Whiterun will feature a lot in the playthrough, so if the OP annoyed the guards to the point of always agro'ing then it'll be a pain.

Comment: If I remember correctly, bounties don't wear off. I think OP has killed a civilian or guard by accident, giving them a 1000 gold bounty. It causes instant aggro. If you just stole something, they will just do a "Hey, do I know you?" emote if you get close or talk to them.

Comment: @Sharain I'm pretty sure that if guards attack you on sight, they will start trying to arrest you again after some time of not being in that town.

Comment: A bounty will always stay in that town until you either face jail or pay up. If you own a house you can easily dump all your stuff there, including money, so you'll just need to face jail.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend immediately pulling out healing spell, dual cast it, make a run for it, and hide somewhere very well hidden, all while casting the spell.

Answer (score 0):

If strong enough, Illusion might do the trick. I found that doing another crime, a small one, will make the yield easier, but the bounty a little higher.

Answer (score -3):

Use some invisibility potions or health potions or run the hell outa there